# How can I iterate Spark's DataFrame rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, iterator

I need to iterate over DataFrame rows.

I don't want to conver it into RDD and filter the desired row each time, e.g.:

```
var index = 0
def next = {
 val result = df.rdd.filter(_._2 == index).collect.map(_._1).headOption
 index += 1
 result
}
```

There is an option to call "collect" method which will return Array[Row], and iterated over it, but I believe it will not hold when having big amount of data.

```
val rowsIterator:Iterator[Row] = df.collect().iterator
rowsIterator.next
```

***UPDATE***:
I was asked to give more information:
I wish to write each row to my DB (in my case ES), but I don't to do it with backpresure in order to make the system more stable.

Comment: what is the purpose of iterations? you should see if any of the [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) can solve your issue. Otherwise you should use udf function. I don't recommend to iterate row by row as you are doing.

Comment: why do u need to iterate? can you elaborate what you are trying to do and share example data?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `df.foreach`?

Comment: df.foreach is not useful for me. I want to take an element (a row) only when my DB is not 'too busy'...

Comment: what is the problem with your current solution?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
val df = ss.range(10000).toDF("i")

val dfEnumerated = df
      .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))))
      .cache()

val collectRnb = (rnb:Int) => dfEnumerated.where($"rnb"===rnb).drop($"rnb").collect.headOption.map(_.getLong(0))
val records : Iterator[Option[Long]] = Iterator.from(1).map(collectRnb)

def next = records.next
```

But this becomes also problematic when dealing with very large datasets, because I used a window-function (`row_number`) without specifying a partitioning, thus this does not scale very well.

You could also use a combination of different methods, e.g. collect 1 partition at a time and iterate through this array.

Edit:

Since Spark 2.0, you can use `.toLocalIterator()` which will collect your data partition-wise:

> Return an iterator that contains all of Rows in this Dataset. The
>   iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this
>   Dataset

Comment: How can I collect 1 partition at a time? foreachPartition is not useful here.

Comment: @user3725190 you can use df.withColumn("partition_id", `spark_partition_id())` and then select und collect 1 partition at a time (you can get all partition ids like that : `val partitions = df.rdd.partitions.map(_.index)`